# Added IK bone messing up excisting animation

Tags: animation, armature, inverse-kinematics

I have downloaded and imported a model from Mixamo. It doens't import right, but after some experimenting I managed to get the existing bones right.

The problem is that I want to add IK to the armature. But adding IK bones messes up the existing animation, because they don't follow along.

I just want to edit a part of the animation with IK. Does anyone have the knowledge on how to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deactivate the IK when needed: Click on the eye icon to deactivate, put your cursor on it and press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert a keyframe. If you want to reactivate, same thing, click on the eye to reactivate and press <kbd>i</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: Agree. If it was for myself, I may also add a Child Of constraint which I would use to "stick" the IK target to its supposed location.  Also play with the influence values, depending on what I need to achieve.
But honestly, it's quite a pain un the foot to tweak an animation which has been baked on ones, sometimes it's just faster to removes some keyframes.

Comment: Thanks for the adequate answer guys, you are heroes! :)

Comment: Blender Task Force always in the place !